# How to set wildcard on System.setProperty in java

Tags: java, git, selenium

May be this a silly question but I cant find an answer.
I have project on git which contain a class where I set system property like bellow

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe")
```

when I clone this project on Linux I get an error which is obvious Linux cant run .exe file then I rename  the file like

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "resources/drivers/geckodriver")
```

and add  geckodriver for Linux. But when once again I run this on windows I get same error, then I change code  to   geckodriver.exe

is there any way to say i set anything you find  resources/drivers/ gecko* run it.

Comment: Before setting the property, you could easily check for the OS and set the value according to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the OS Name and apply conditional statement.

You can try like below:

```
String osname = System.getProperty("os.name");

if(osname.startsWith("Linux")){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "resources/drivers/geckodriver") 
  }else if(osname.startsWith("Windows")){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe") 
  }
```

You need to keep both `geckodriver` for Linux and Windows under `resources/drivers/` path.